# Sum of Two Infinitesimals being Infinitesimal

Tags: calculus, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

Any hyperreal number greater than 0 and smaller than all positive real numbers is infinitesimal.
We know the sum of two infinitesimals is infinitesimal.
Let $A$ be the smallest positive real number.
Let $dx$ be an infinitesimal.
$(A - dx)$ is an infinitesimal as it is less than all positive real numbers

$(A - dx) + dx$ is the sum of two infinitesimals, which under non standard analysis, is infinitesimal.
However, I thought that non standard algebra followed the rules of standard algebra, so shouldn't the sum $(A - dx) + dx$ be $A$, a standard real number, and not an infinitesimal? Is there a way around this contradiction? Thanks

Edit: Fixed equation formatting

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You made an assumption to get to that contradiction. One way around the contradiction is that the assumption is false, that there is no such $A$.

Comment: $\frac{A}{2}$ is a real number smaller than $A$?

Comment: "Let  be the smallest positive real number." You cannot assume that there exists a "smallest positive real number". There doesn't.

Comment: @DanAsimov You can assume whatever you want. In particular, that's how proofs by contradiction work.

Comment: NDB — of course you are right about assumptions. But the OP was using the word "assume" for the purpose of giving "the smallest positive real number" a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks guys, so the answer is that $A$ cannot be assumed to exist because it doesn't, as there is always a smaller real number

Comment: You can assume it. That's fine. You just get a contradiction, when you do.